# ServiceBus Dequeue trigger message Unmarshalling Golang custom handler in azure : message format

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions

Hello i created a golang custom handler for Azure functions. I have a queue with messages that i need to dequeue and process. However when I try to process the message I cannot unmarshall its content.  I'm following this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers#examples   of course i adapted it to work with gingonic but still I have not been able to solve the problem. Shouldn't the dequeued message be in JSON and easily deserialized/unmarshalled? Seems to be in some sort of scaped string that i don't know how to deal with using golang. Any help is welcomed.
Below : the function.json, the code snippet, and the log message of how the payload looks plus the error.

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myitem",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "new-mwsgs",
      "connection": "my_connectionstr",
      "accessRights": "listen",
      "dataType": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

```golang
type InvokeRequest struct {
    Data     map[string]json.RawMessage
    Metadata map[string]interface{}
}
type MyItem strutc{
    ID string `json:"id"`
    IDnum int `json:"id_num"`
    Flags map[string]interface{} `json:"flags"`

}

func  Post(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var req InvokeRequest

    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&req); err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        
    }
    logrus.Info(req.Data["myitem"])

   var myItem MyItem
   if err:= json.Unmarshal([invokeRequest.Data["myitem"], &myItem); err !=nil{
logrus.Error(err)
}

ctx.Status(http.StatusOK)


}
```

logs

```
2021-03-26T15:59:04Z   [Error]   time="2021-03-26T15:59:03Z" level=info msg="map[myitem:\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"605e04c7fd8f28e17f747952\\\",\\\"id_num\\\":666,\\\"flags\\\":{\\\"eligible\\\":true,\\\"nationwide\\\":true,\\\"persistent_\\\":false}}\"]\"" 
2021-03-26T15:59:04Z   [Error]   time="2021-03-26T15:59:03Z" level=error msg="json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type MyItem"
```

Comment: What happens if you unmarshal it first into a string, rather than `json.RawMessage` and then just convert that string into a byte slice and unmarshal that into `&myItem`? e.g. change Data field's type like so `Data     map[string]string` and then pass `[]byte(invokeRequest.Data["myitem"])` to json.Unmarshal.

Comment: it turns it into a bytes array, but it wouldn't unmarshal correctly. I posted the way i got it to work below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i fixed it. I added a `strconv.Unquote`  before Unmarshaling. Works now.

```golang
myItemStr, _:= strconv.Unquote(invokeRequest.Data["myitem"])
  var myItem MyItem
   if err:= json.Unmarshal([]byte(myItemStr), &myItem); err !=nil{
logrus.Error(err)
}
```